# How to convert asp web api byte[] to pdf file in Angular 8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, pdf, blob

I've been having some problems when I try to convert a byte[] coming from C# into a pdf file using Angular.
When I perform the conversion the file is created but is corrupted and it can't be opened "We can't open this file", the file content is just basic text "Hello world".
Please let me know if you have any answer to this problem, the code I am using is below and I also try using *"import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';"* but it didn't work.

```
   // THE WEB API CONTROLLER THAT GETS THE PDF BYTE ARRAY
   [HttpPost("CreatePDF")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreatePDF([FromBody] PDFContent pdfContent)
    {
        byte[] pdf = await _pdfGenerator.GeneratePDF(pdfContent.HtmlContent);
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }



      // UI SERVICE LAYER THAT CALLS THE SERVER SIDE
      createPdfReport(pdfContent: PDFContent): Observable<any> {
       return this.restApi.create("CreatePDF",pdfContent).pipe(
       tap(pdf =>
          console.log('pdf = ' + pdf)
        ));
       }



// THE COMPONENT THAT CALLS THE SERVICE LAYER AND WAITS FOR THE RESPONSE
this.historyService.createPdfReport(pdfContent).subscribe(data => {
  var file = new Blob(data, { type: 'application/octet-stream' })      
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  link.setAttribute('href', fileURL);
  link.setAttribute('download', `file.pdf`);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  link.remove();
 });
```

}

This is the response I get in Angular after the controller returns the byte[]:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] post with your debugging results - in particular how response look over HTTP, what data you get at each step (presumable `pdf`, `data` and `fileUrl` variables should contain something related to the file).

Comment: I just updated the question with the response I get from the controller